# Trying to understand how to handle user data. or maybe better worded user input

Tags: json, input, storage, backend

I am learning JS and react.  A lot of the online resources I am using tend to teach simple apps or fetch data from an API and work with the json.

What I am interested in doing is to take user input...
for example. in a form element a user will enter like a name, level, type, image/video.  (I think instagram profile page is fair example).

Id like to do two things with the input
1 create a profile page
2 create a list of posts

and ideally later create a way for users to sync the names of the input since its for a thing that does not have a common language or vocabulary.

I saw someone create their own json data file and then map over the json request with react?  Or do I need a backend?  I have yet to understand what to do with the data and how to store it.
Maybe learn node js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the project you have in mind.
Preferably you can create a simple backend using **Node** and **Express**, with **MongoDB** as your database, if you add **React** as the front-end framework, this is going to be **MERN stack** which is very popular, you can Google it!

I recommend learning a bit Node, Express, and MongoDB (you do not need to learn everything about MongoDB! you can use **Mongoose** as the DB tool in your Express app),
Then save and retrieve your data using React.